# SQL Server connection with GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, sql-server

Is it possible to connect to a SQL Server database with GRASS?

I tried this way:

```
>db.connect driver=ODBC database='dbname=mydb,host=myserv'
(Mon Dec 12 15:34:27 2016) Completed (0 sec)`
```

But next, when I try to show a list of tables:

```
>db.tables
-p                                                                    
ERROR: Unable to open database <dbname=mydb,host=myserv>
```

The database is hosted on a server on my local network and I use GRASS 7.0.5 and SQL Server 12

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string probably is wrong (has comma instead of semicolon). Try using something like

```
db.connect driver=ODBC database='dbname=mydb;host=myserv'
```

and then use

```
db.login
```

As suggested in the docs: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/db.connect.html

Or try experimenting with ODBC connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/ .

Also, it may be you need a DSN for ODBC access, the docs mention it: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/branches/releasebranch_7_0/db/drivers/odbc/grass-odbc.html

Comment: I tried but without success. Judging by this tutorial http://www.northrivergeographic.com/grass-connecting-to-postgis-using-the-gui ,it seems to be a comma separator and apostrophes are not necessary. I tried with the server's IP adress instead of the name, and also using db.login first. It doesn't work.

Comment: Please check the documentation in GRASS GIS 7 as well: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/db.connect.html#odbc may require the use of db.login https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/db.login.html